# Query to list all galleries under a parent post?

Tags: shortcode, query, query-posts, child-pages

I have many child galleries organized by their parent galleries (multiple parent galleries with several child galleries under).

I would like to create a shortcode that is able to query all the child galleries under a specified parent gallery. I'm having a bit of difficulty... anyone care to help me out?

This is the function that I have so far:

```
function display_gallery_cards($atts) { 
global $post; 

    $defaults = array(
        'sort_column' => menu_order,
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => '',
        'depth' => 1,
        'echo' => 0,
        'parentgal' => '',
        'walker' => new Thumbnail_walker()

    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $childpages = wp_list_pages(array(
        'sort_column' => menu_order,
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $args['parentgal'],
        'depth' => 1,
        'echo' => 0,
        'walker' => new Thumbnail_walker()
    ));

    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<ul class="two-columns">' . $childpages . '</ul><div class="clearfix"></div>';
    }
return $string;
}
add_shortcode( 'list-cards', 'display_gallery_cards' );
```

When I do [list-cards parentgal='941'] the output displays fine, but it's displaying the wrong pages. Am I passing on the "parent gallery" post ID correctly?

Comment: In your function `$parentgal` variable doesn't exist. As far as I can tell in your given functions code you're not doing anything with the passed `$atts` variable either. I suggest checking out the [`wp_parse_args()` function.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args) and edit your question ( using the edit link above ) to update your functions code.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've edited my code, does this look right?

Comment: So using your code above, when you view the page with the short code posted in your question that has the id passed to it `941` you don't see the subpage that belong under page id `941`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that's correct. It seems to be displaying random parent/top-level posts, instead of child posts.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee solved! Solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the post type in the query.

```
'post_type' => 'gallery'
```

Problem solved!